# Insert Query in C# with MS access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledb

When I am inserting data in MS access database .it is not giving any error but data not inserted in database

**code:**

```
  private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int row = dataGridView1.RowCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < row - 1; i++)
        {
            String str = "insert into JDS_Data(job_no,order_no,Revision,DesignSpec,Engine_Type,date,LE_IN_Designer,CPH_Designer,Exp_Del_Week,Action_code,Rev_Description,Ref_pattern,Name_of_mock_up,EPC_Drawing,Turbocharger_no_Type,Engine_Specific_Requirement,Draft_sketch_with_details,Air_cooler_type,Description_of_Job,SF_No,Standard,Prority_Sequence,Remark,Part_family,Modified_Date,User) values('" + txtjobno.Text + "','" + txtorderno.Text + "','" + txtrevison.Text + "','" + txtds.Text + "','" + txtenginetype.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + txtleindesigner.Text + "','" + txtcphdesigner.Text + "','" + txtexpweek.Text + "','" + txtactioncode.Text + "','" + txtrevdescription.Text + "','" + txtrefpatern.Text + "','" + txtmockup.Text + "','" + txtepcdwg.Text + "','" + txtturbono.Text + "','" + txtenginereq.Text + "','" + txtdraft.Text + "','" + txtaircolertype.Text + "','" + txtdespjob.Text + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "','" + DateTime.Today + "','" + mdlconnection.user_name + "')";

            int dd = mdlconnection.excuteQuery(str);
            MessageBox.Show(str);
            //if (dd > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully..!!!");

            }

        }

    }
```

Code:

```
    public static int excuteQuery(string q)
    {
        int d = 0;
        try
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con);
            d = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: What does `mdlconnection.excuteQuery` method exactly? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Update this in your question with [edit] button under it.

Comment: ExcuteQuery is :public static int excuteQuery(string q)
        {
            int d = 0;
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q, con);
                d = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return d;
        }

Comment: it is not giving error but data not inserted in database ..other forms are working

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx) (you provided to little info)
you should rewrite your statement to match the example:

```
var customers = db.ExecuteQuery<Customer>(@"SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, 
   Address, City, Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax
   FROM   dbo.Customers
   WHERE  City = {0}", "London");
```

I should suggest to use [this tutorial for the connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx) instead actually